# Trying to separate one alert into 2 alerts

Tags: javascript, php

I have a code that identifies data from a "json" file the data comes as follows:

```
{ "id""1405853194651","title:"hello ","data" : ["test1","test2"]}
```

I would like to separate the "test1" and "test2" to separate alerts

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var delay = null;
     function loadXMLDoc(){
        if (delay) {
            clearTimeout(delay);
        }
        var sec = 2000;
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'alert.php');
        xhr.responseType = 'text';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {

        const final = this.response;
        
        if (final !== ""){
         {
                sec = 10000;
                iff(final); // call to iff function - send to aplication.
            }
        }else{
            document.getElementById("name").textContent = "There are no alerts at the moment";
        }
        delay = setTimeout(loadXMLDoc,sec);
        }
        }
        
        xhr.send();
    };

        window.onload = function() {
            loadXMLDoc();
        }

    </script>
    <script>
        function iff(final){
        const object = JSON.parse(final);

        /* Join elements of data array in object to a comma separated string */
        const value = object.data.join(",");
        
        var zone = value;
        document.getElementById("name").textContent = zone;
         $.post("sendtofirebase.php", {zone: zone}, function(data) {
            // returned from php
         });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<text id="name"></text>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
</body>
```

What displays the alerts is the following code

```
const value = object.data.join(",");
```

That the alert reaches the cell phone, it arrives like this

Hello
test1,test2

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not at all clear what your specific problem or question is here or what the expected results are. What do you need from us?

Comment: ......and thats not valid JSON object too.

Comment: This is a server that receives data from JSON file and sends you to the cell phone device through Firebase. I want to send 2 separate alerts and not one alert with the 2 objects that are in json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  function iff(final){
    const object = JSON.parse(final);
    
    for (let err of object.data) {
      var zone = err;
      document.getElementById("name").textContent = zone;
      $.post("sendtofirebase.php", {zone: zone}, function(data) {
        // returned from php
      });
    }
}
</script>
```